# How can a constraint be violated when the SQL query excludes it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a result table that holds the output of a large, complicated, slow running query.

It's defined something like:

```sql
create table ResultsStore (
    Foo int not null,
    Bar int not null,
    ... other fields
    constraint [PK_ResultsStore_foo_bar] primary key clustered
    (
        Foo asc,
        Bar asc
    )
)
```

I then insert to this table with a query like:

```sql
insert ResultsStore (Foo, Bar) 
output inserted.* 
select subQuery.ID, @bar
from ( 
    -- large complex slow query
    ) subQuery
where subQuery.ID not in ( 
        select Foo 
        from ResultsStore 
        where Bar = @bar 
    )
```

In testing this is fine, but in production, with lots of users hitting it regularly, we often get an exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ResultsStore_foo_bar'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'ResultsStore'.

How is this possible? Surely the `where` should exclude any combination of the multiple primary key fields where they are already in the table?

How to best avoid this?

Comment: Normally I'd expect the server to guarantee everything in a single statement is atomic: the statement doesn't start until it can get enough locks to ensure it can finish uninterrupted. But perhaps the isolation level is set too low, or perhaps some queries are using things like nolock hints to avoid issuing needed locks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'll check it, some of the sub query might be using `nolock`, but even if it were, wouldn't a dirty/uncomitted read _exclude_ rows that haven't been added yet, rather than _include_ rows that already have been committed?

Comment: Nolock works by not issuing a lock, allowing other queries to read dirty data. So if another query uses nolock, this query might start and let the subquery read dirty data initially indicating there's no matching (ID, Bar) pair, which then fails as the INSERT part tries to write the data (because it's only _read_ uncommitted, not write uncommitted).

Comment: You could also try using *not exists* instead (always preferable); Have you looked at snapshot isolation?

Comment: If your large complex slow query itself is yielding duplicate records, not yet in the ResultsStore, your NOT IN or NOT EXISTS check will pass them, but they will still trigger a duplicate key violation on insert.  For example, if complex slow query yields [{1,2}, {1,2}] and {1,2} is not yet in ResultsStore, you will get an error on insert.  It might be a rare case where you actually need a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @stu tested with snapshot isolation - the problem is the large and slow subquery (over about 7 million records with an FTI) is painful with snapshot isolation. I want the sub query to be dirty (a fast, maybe out of date, response is far preferred to waiting to access the relevant tables).

Comment: @TN the subquery groups by the ID being inserted, so it shouldn't be possible, but I'll check.

Comment: Note that dirty reads with NOLOCK not only allow uncommitted data to be read, data can be skipped or duplicated in the result during IAM scans due to concurrent data modifications.

Comment: You need `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` on the subquery to avoid this race condition. At default read committed isolation level the S locks taken by the sub query are released as soon as the row is read and they don't protect the range where the row would exist in the event that there is no matching row anyway. The `HOLDLOCK` gives serializable semantics and protects the range. `UPDLOCK` makes the pattern less deadlock prone if run concurrently by different processes. Snapshot won't help you as you need to read the state *now* not at the start of the statement

Comment: And also with the above you would want an index with leading column Bar so the index key range can be locked efficiently. RE: "a fast, maybe out of date, response is far preferred" this is exactly what is causing the issue. You require an exactly up-to-date response with no possibility of any discrepancies between the time it is read and the insert is done or you run the risk of these errors. You can use `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` if you want to silently ignore them

Comment: SERIALIZABLE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Most likely - you have duplicates in the query itself, even if it doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a temp table to hold interim results and perform the final insert at the end.

The following also includes a `DISTINCT` (which might or might not be needed), changes the dup test to use `EXISTS`, and applies `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` options to the final insert as suggested by others.

```
declare @TempResults table (
    Foo int not null,
    Bar int not null
)

insert @TempResults
select distinct subQuery.ID, @bar
from ( 
    -- large complex slow query
    ) subQuery

insert ResultsStore (Foo, Bar) 
output inserted.* 
select T.Foo, T.Bar
from @TempResults T
where not exists ( 
   select * 
   from ResultsStore RS with (updlock, holdlock, rowlock)
   where RS.Foo = T.Foo
   and RS.Bar = T.Bar
)
```

This lets your long running query run fast and dirty (as you intend), but should maintain integrity and minimize actual lock duration for the final insert.

Comment: This gives me an exception: _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon._, but it works if I move it to after the `from`, so `from ResultsStore RS with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

As written two sessions can run the query, both checking for the existence of the row concurrently, both not finding it, then both proceeding to attempt the insert.  The first one will succeed in READ COMMITED, and the second one will fail.

You need `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` on the subquery to avoid this race condition. At default read committed isolation level either S locks taken by the sub query or row versioning is used and no locks at all are taken.

The HOLDLOCK gives serializable semantics and protects the range. UPDLOCK forces the read to use a U lock which will block other sessions from reading with UPDLOCK.